# WPF TextBox binding to numeric or DateTime fields/properties

Tags: c#, wpf, dependencies, bindingsource

I've seen many references of make a TextBox only allow numeric entry... no problem, I understand how to do that.  However, the typical binding is still to the "Text" (TextProperty dependency) of the TextBox which is a string value.

If the value being entered is being forced to that of a numeric (say... either integer, or double, float for final storage), how would you go about having the correct 2-way binding to say

```
TextBox.MyInteger
TextBox.MyDouble
TextBox.MyFloat
TextBox.MyDateTime
```

So, if I had a class that had (for example)

```
public class MyRecord
{
   public int IntegerOnly { get; set; }
   public double DoubleOnly { get; set; }
   public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a TextBox on a window for entry, with applicable behaviors/filters to ONLY allow numeric (and decimal point) value to be entered into the TextBox, the display to the user is via the shown "Text" value.

So, I want an instance of the "MyRecord.IntegerOnly" to get the numeric value pushed back (to the database) and forth (to the view for the user to see/edit).

Since everything in C# is type-cast, I don't see any "implied" or "conversion" value from the text to numeric.

Similarly, for doing data entry of a DATE or DATETIME TextBox control.  No implied / converted value...

How can / should I proceed with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if I'm not understanding your question, but the `Binding` class handles conversions of basic types for you. `TextBox.Text` can only ever show string/text value regardless of what it is bound to (int, double, DateTime, etc.). The `Binding` is responsible for converting values back-and-forth between target and source, i.e., `Int32 -> String` (to target) and `String -> Int32` (back to source).

You can very easily designate a `TextBox` to only accept `DateTime` values knowing that the user is going to enter them as a `String` and the `Binding` will convert it to the expected `DateTime` value. When you need to convert values not automatically handled by the `Binding`, you need to provide your own `IValueConverter`.

Does that answer your question or have I missed the point?

Comment: I THINK you've answered it, I'll try some sampling.

Comment: Thanks... I guess I was over-thinking it with all the other strong-typed stuff, didn't get internally it was autoMagically converting to proper data type to/from.